# DevExpress separate filters / sorting for GridViews in GridControl

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, devexpress

The controls mentioned are from the `DevExpress` framework.

I'm using a `TabControl` and within the `tab pages` I always display the same `GridControl` (changing its parent). To give an idea, each tab is a different file, and the grid shows some content of it.

Anyway, my idea was that I could simply extend the Tab, add a `GridView` to each of them together with a `BindingList` for the data source and swap the `MainView` + `DataSource` on the main `GridControl` whenever the tap page is selected.

**This works fine so far.**

However, the applied filter / column on the `Grid` is applied on every `GridView` (globally), seems like this is stored on the `GridControl` instead.

Long story short, is there a way to **keep** the filter / column sort **separately** for **each** `GridView`, or do I have to programmatically store the filters / column sortings every time I switch the tab?

Maybe this is even stupid and I should be using multiple `GridControls` with their own `GridViews` each or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two thoughts on how you could accomplish this.

1. Instantiate your GridControl and GridView as a singleton, and make sure that each tab page calls the singleton rather than instantating a new grid.  In this manner, any changes to one will persist natively.

The disadvantage to this approach is you may lose some of your design-time capabilities or have to hack your way around them, for example creating a dummy form that has your grid and build your singleton off of it.

2. Create a global static property of some type that contains the XML for the grid layout.  On your `SelectedPageChanged` event of your `XtraTabbedMdiManager`, this is when you would get the XML and apply it to that page's grid.

Here is a sample of #2:

Public property to store the filename for the current layout.  Assume this is in a static class named `Globals`:

```
private static string _CurrentLayoutFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
public static string CurrentLayoutFile
{
    get { return _CurrentLayoutFile; }
}
```

When the layout is changed, you want to capture the current layout XML and save it using the global filename:

```
private void gridView1_Layout(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView1.SaveLayoutToXml(Globals.CurrentLayoutFile);
}
```

On your `SelectedPageChanged` event, assign the saved layout:

```
private void xtraTabbedMdiManager1_SelectedPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DevExpress.XtraTabbedMdi.XtraMdiTabPage page = xtraTabbedMdiManager1.SelectedPage;
    if (page != null && File.Exists(Globals.CurrentLayoutFile))
    {
        gridView1.RestoreLayoutFromXml(Globals.CurrentLayoutFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, got what I wanted. Due to some other dependencies I decided to create a `GridControl` for each `TabPage` and thus each of them has their own filter / find / sorted column which it will "remember".

Still interested if this is the common way to do it, or if there are nicer solutions out there. :-)